# Need a solution to replace ActiveX that can be used from web browsers\ HTML 5

Tags: html, browser, activex

I have a windows service that firing events and use local connected devices like scanners and such.
Until today if i wanted to use it from a web page i had to use an active x component that i created (a wrapper for my windows service SDK).
But the modern web browsers stopping their usage with Active X and HTML 5 not support active X.
I need an ideas or other solution that i cam move on to.
Any help is very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have been in this kind of situation before. What we have done is to create a browser extension (Chrome in our case) that uses `Native Messaging` to communicate with a locally deployed application. (exe in our case, which is also needed to be registered in Windows Registry). Extension serves as a message broker between the content script and the native application.

[Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging)

Comment: Thanks but i search something that is not a browser related (don't want to create browser extension for each browser type)

Comment: @LeeShadmi you don't need to create for each. Most browsers support Chrome's extension model. There is a nice [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Build_a_cross_browser_extension) about developing a cross-browser extension.